# Awstat static page generation year-level result file empty

Tags: awstats

I've been trying to get weblog statistics for year level with AwStats (7.6 (build 20161204)), but with no luck. The main file awstats.service.html ends up being  empty. I am able to generate the static report pages for one month and there all files seem to be ok, but not for the year level.

Could not find from [Awstat forum](https://sourceforge.net/p/awstats/discussion/43428/) that there would be a known bug of this sort.

Command line:

```
 /usr/share/awstats/tools/awstats_buildstaticpages.pl -config=ourservice -awstatsprog=/usr/share/awstats/wwwroot/cgi-bin/awstats.pl -dir=/var/www/html/aw/2017  -month=all -year=2017
```

All other static pages are generated, but the awstats.service.html is empty.

Running awstats.pl directly ends up to pretty same situation. Cannot get the year-level report from there either, but month level reports come out ok.

Awstats configuration settings are the default ones, except for file paths etc. and e.g.

```
Expires=3600
DNSLookup=0
```

Probably have to dig into the script, to see why that one file ends up being empty, but if anyone has an idea or seen something like this, thank you for any hints.

Addition1: Static page generation seems to use plain awstats.pl. That script   stops with 'Killed' message some time after it has printed out beginning of body tag.

Comment: Any reason why you prefer AWSTATS rather than proper analytics?

Comment: I was wondering the same thing. I was a web host for many years. It was easy for me to offer Awstat but I thought it was poor at best. I used SawMill instead. Try Piwik. It is free and one of the very best out there.

Comment: Awstat is the one that has been used for long time for statistics, so changes require explanations. We are trying to transfer to use other methods, but just in case would like to have these available in back pocket.